# What is the difference between normal distribution and standard normal distribution?

Tags: normal-distribution

While studying statistics I am stuck with a question of 5 difference between normal and standard normal distribution.

1. Standard normal dist. has mean 0 and standard deviation 1 and for
   normal dist. it can be any positive value.
2. You can convert normal dist. to standard  normal dist.(i.e
   normalization or standardization) but reverse is possible only when
   you have mean and standard deviation of normal dist.

what are the other difference?

Comment: In 1, the mean of a normal distribution can take any real value

Comment: In 2 you need some information about the (non-standard) normal distribution if you want to be able to standardise it

Comment: Anything which depends on scale or location will potentially be different, such as the fourth raw moment or the probability of being positive

Comment: The second statement is a bit vague. What does "convert" mean in "You can convert normal dist. to standard normal dist."? Please try to express this statement more precisely. You might find out that it was not completely clear to yourself what you meant.